# employ bootstrap in sharepoint master page without SPD

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am a new sharepoint(2010) user and every now and then I'd ratter use my own coding instead of the alternative options that sharepoint gives me .I've found that I can add some HTML and CSS(inline) but it would be lot more convenient if I could add a separate stylesheet and employ bootsrap with in my HTML.It seems that I can do so by modifying the master page however I dont have sharepoint designer.
Is there any possibility that meet what I want with out SPD . If yes ? how ?

Answer (score 1):

you could do that manualy or by dev (with a Visual Studio project, and use wsp). But the using of SharePoint Designer (a free tools) is better and more simple.

To do tha manualy :

1. You can create a master page locally (dev your master page)
2. On your site : enable the Publishing feature
3. After, you can go to the Master pages galleries (link in site setting) for uploading your new master page (don't forget to checkin publish your master page in the gallerie)
4. Go to site settings, under Look and feel, select : Master page
5. And here, you can change your site master page manually (and choosing your new master)